# Alert dialog not closing - "Cancelling event due to no window focus"

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have an Alert Dialog of type TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT with 2 buttons Ok & Cancel. The OK button opens a new activity where the Cancel button just dismisses the dialog.

The alert it's being displayed 2 times one on top on the other - and if the Cancel button is pressed for the visible dialog - it's being dismissed and the second one it's being displayed and everything works as it should.

My problem is when selecting OK from the visible dialog - the required activity is being opened, the current dialog is being dismissed but a weird thing is happening - the activity is displayed beneath the first dialog and when trying to select one of the buttons the message error `"Dropping event due to no window focus: MotionEvent"` is displayed - and the dialog can not be accessed anymore.

I've tried with an event to request focus for the remaining Alert - something like:

```
 this.mAlertDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setFocusable(true); 
 this.mAlertDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
 this.mAlertDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().requestFocus();
```

or

```
this.mAlertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).requestFocus();
```

but no change.

Comment: You have to post complete reproducable code.

Comment: @Alin Were you able to fix this problem? If so, please post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these

```
this.mAlertDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setCancelable(true);
```

OR

```
this.mAlertDialog.setCancelable(true);
```

OR

```
...onclick(View v) {
this.mAlertDialog.cancel();
}
```

OR

```
...onclick(View v) {
this.mAlertDialog.dimiss();
}
```